# Looking to to determine Elapsed Time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am working on a project where I am determining the time between two times. The times are in the format HH:MM AM/PM. How would you convert this to an elapsed time in hours and minutes?

Here is the code below.

```
  <?php

$flightcount = 0;
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo1 = Database::connect();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM FlightBasic ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(DepartTime, '%l:%i %p')";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Connections";
$Org = $_GET["origin"];
$Dest = $_GET["destination"];
$DDate = $_GET["ddate"];
$ADate = $_GET["adate"];
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM connections";

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
if($row["Date"] == $DDate){


if($row["Date"] == $DDate){

foreach ($pdo1->query($sql2) as $row2) {
    $conn = $row2["Connection"];
if($row2["Origin"]==$Org && $row2["Destination"]==$Dest){
if($row["Origin"]==$Org && $row["Destination"]==$conn){
    $fldpt = $row["DepartTime"];
    $flarr = $row["ArriveTime"];
    $flnum = $row["FlightNumber"];
    $sql3 = "";
    echo 
    $fltr = $row2["TravelTime"];

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    if($row["Origin"]==$conn && $row["Destination"]==$Dest){        

        echo '<tr style="color:black; height:20px; background-color:#95AFB8">';
echo '<td align="center">' . $fldpt . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center" >' . $flarr . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center" >' . $flnum . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="2" width="108">1 Stop: <br> Stops In ' . $row2['Connection'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center" valign="center" rowspan="2">' . $fltr . '</td>';


echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr style="color:black; height:20px; background-color:#DFEBF0">';
echo '<td align="center" width="82">' . $row['DepartTime'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center" width="84">' . $row['ArriveTime'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center" width="94">' . $row['FlightNumber'] . '</td>';

echo '</tr>';

    }
}
}
}
}
}



if($row["Origin"]==$Org && $row["Destination"]==$Dest){
echo '<tr style="color:black; height:40px; background-color:#95AFB8">';
echo '<td align="center">' . $row['DepartTime'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center">' . $row['ArriveTime'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center">' . $row['FlightNumber'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center">Nonstop</td>';
echo '<td align="center">' . $row['TravelTime'] . '</td>';


echo '</tr>';
}
}
}

  Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you even googled first

Comment: I've looked all over and can't find anything with my situation.

Comment: what you posted in definitely some code. Perhaps now you can pair it down to make it the *relevant* code to your question.  Here is how to deal with DateIntervals in PHP. Maybe to point you in the right direction: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: `strtotime($foo) - strtotime($bar)` -> elapsed seconds, basically.

Comment: @MarcB would that work if the time for example was '3:45 PM' and '4:45 PM'?

Comment: test it and find out. strtotime can be magical sometimes, but it's not omniscient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code calculating difference between times. Your code has nothing clear on what you really want, therefor, transform this according to your needs.

```
    <?php
$first  = new DateTime( Your time );
$second = new DateTime( Another time );

$diff = $first->diff( $second );
```

This prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM

```
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

    echo $diff->format( '%H:%I:%S' ); // -> Difference

        ?>
```

The A (or a) shows the AM / PM format. More details in PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: This works but it does not take the PM into consideration. How would you incorporate the PM hours to this?

Comment: And by the way, Googling would be better :) We are here to help, not to "freelance" for others.